# Touch Event for UIImageView is not working for all images in iOS

Tags: uiview, ios6, uiimageview, touch

I Place the imgaes as below.

In ListView.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad()
 {
        int j=5;
        for (int i=0; i<[po_id_array count]; i++) {

                ViewForTickImage *tickimage=[[ViewForTickImage alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, j, 35, 35)];

                NSLog(@"----------%d",j);
                j=j+17;
                [tickimage setTick:FALSE];
                [tickimage setTag:i];
               // [tickimage setDelegate:self];
                [self.view addSubview:tickimage];

            }

        }
```

In ViewForTickImage.h file the code is as follows:

```
@interface ViewForTickImage : UIView
{
    BOOL ticked;
    NSMutableArray *list_selected;
    id delegate;
    UIImageView *currentImg;
    AppDelegate *appdelegate;

}
//@property(nonatomic,readwrite)BOOL ticked;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite,getter=isTicked,setter=setTick:)BOOL ticked;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *currentImg;
-(void)checkTickVisiblilityForListAllView;
```

In ViewForTickImage.m file the code is::

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        currentImg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        [currentImg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_unselect.png"];
        [currentImg setImage:img];
        [self addSubview:currentImg];
    }
    return self;
}

    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

   NSLog(@"image selected");

}
```

It displays the column of images.Touch event is working only for first image.How to fire the touch event for all images.Please give the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using imageView try using UIbutton and add image to the image property of the button. yoU can identify the click in a simple way.
Using tag property of the button you can identify which button was clicked.

```
   UIButton *imageButton1;
   imageButton1.tag=buttonIdentifier;
   [imageButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I tried with button also but the same target event is also working for first button not for all.Please suggest about it.

Comment: Add same target to all button  and in target, based on the button tag value implement the required operation.

set different tag for each button

Comment: for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            UIButton *imageButton1=[[UIButton alloc] init];
            imageButton1.frame=CGRectMake(5, j, 35, 35);
            imageButton1.tag=i;
            [imageButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
             imageButton1.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_unselect.png"]];
            [self addSubview:imageButton1];
             j=j+34;
        }

Comment: -(void)imageSelected:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"%d image selected",[sender tag]);
}Then also issue not fixed.

Comment: Then also It is not working.Can you suggest where I did wrong

Comment: Whats the value of the tag when button is clicked? also try incrementing j by more  value j=j+40 may be buttons are getting overlapped

Comment: Every time it is giving 0.If I click the button other than first it does not goes to target method.Only when I click the first button It works.

Comment: This code is working perfect

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        UIButton *imageButton1=[[UIButton alloc] init];
        imageButton1.frame=CGRectMake(5, j, 35, 35);
        imageButton1.tag=i;
        [imageButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        imageButton1.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm.gif"]]; [self.view addSubview:imageButton1];
        j=j+50;
    }

}
-(void)imageSelected:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d",[sender tag]);
}

Comment: Actually I am customizing the buttons or ImageViews using UIView then in UIView class we should not have viewDidAppear method.I will edit the code.

Comment: I just gave an example. You can try pasting that code anywhere it will work fine.

Comment: First check the frame height and width.Here my problem is I gave the height as minimum valve that is the whole reason. Now It is working.

Comment: so change the self.frame=CGRectMake() value.